# 404 Not found error in suds request send - python - django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, suds

I'm setting up online payment portal to my website.
I use below code:

```
ZARINPAL_WEBSERVICE ='https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/services/WebGate/wsdl'  # Required
MERCHANT_ID = 'blah-blah-blah'  # Required
amount = 0

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class Upgrade(View):
    def get(self, request):
        current_plan = UserPlan.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
        all_plans = Plans.objects.all()
        old_plans = None
        if current_plan:
            new_plans = all_plans.filter(no__gt=current_plan.no)
            old_plans = all_plans.filter(no__lte=current_plan.no)
        else:
            new_plans = all_plans

        return render(request, 'business/upgrade.html', {'current_plan': current_plan,
                                                     'new_plans': new_plans,
                                                     'old_plans': old_plans})

    def post(self, request):
        current_plan = UserPlan.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
        form = UpgradeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_plan = form.cleaned_data.get('requested_plan')
            requested_plan = Plans.objects.filter(no=new_plan).first()
            global amount
            if current_plan:
                amount = requested_plan.price - current_plan.price
            else:
                amount = requested_plan.price

            # redirect to ZarinPal page and send data to it
            description = u'TEST DESCRIPTION'  # Required
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')  # Optional
            mobile = form.cleaned_data.get('phone')  # Optional
            CallbackURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/business/verify/'
            client = Client(ZARINPAL_WEBSERVICE)
            result = client.service.PaymentRequest(MERCHANT_ID, amount, description, email, mobile, CallbackURL)
            if result.Status == 100:
                return redirect('https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/StartPay/' + result.Authority)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Error')
        else:
            messages.error(request, form.errors)
            print(form.errors)
            return redirect('upgrade_plan')


@login_required
def verify(request):
    client = Client(ZARINPAL_WEBSERVICE)
    if request.GET.get('Status') == 'OK':
        result = client.service.PaymentVerification(MMERCHANT_ID,
                                                request.GET['Authority'],
                                                amount)
        if result.Status == 100:
            # in this step, it must create or update UserPlan row in DB.
        # also, it should be create a row in Sells table and save transaction defatils.

            return HttpResponse('Transaction was successfull. RefID: ' + str(result.RefID))
        elif result.Status == 101:
            return HttpResponse('Transaction submitted : ' + str(result.Status))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Transaction failed. Status: ' + str(result.Status))
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Transaction failed or canceled by user')
```

But before it shows me payment gate, it generates an error:

> Exception at /business/upgrade/ 
>   (404, 'Not Found')
>   Request Method:   POST
>   Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/business/upgrade/
>   Django Version:   1.11.4
>   Exception Type:   Exception
>   Exception Value:
>   (404, 'Not Found')

and the error is for this line of code:

```
result = client.service.PaymentRequest(MERCHANT_ID, amount, description, email, mobile, CallbackURL)
```

What's the problem? and how can I solve that?
thanks

*** UPDATE*** 
the below snippet is my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    # for explicit urls
    url(r'^upgrade/$', views.Upgrade.as_view(), name='upgrade_plan'),
    url(r'^verify/$', views.verify, name='verify'),
]
```

Comment: Please show your actual view and URLs.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you for comment. I updated code in question and added whole views.py file.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things here that don't make any sense.

Firstly, you can't tell your payment provider to make a callback to your site with a 127.0.0.1 address. That's just your localhost; but obviously the gateway is elsewhere on the Internet. It needs to have an actual address for your site which it can call.

Secondly, unrelated to your question but still a very serious problem, you must absolutely not use global variables like this. Those will be shared by all users of your site, so the amounts will get all mixed up. I don't know anything about this payment provider, but I'm absolutely certain that it will provide the amount in the parameters of the callback.

Comment: there were some example codes in the gate provider website that showed working with localhost has no problem, but I'm not sure, maybe if I upload that codes to my server, problem be solved.

Comment: The problem was for suds library. I used "zeep" library and the problem solved. but I have a question, you said I shouldn't use `global amount` in my code, so how can I use it in second function? it will be used in `verify` function. so how to send it to second function (`verify`) ?

Comment: As I said, it is absolutely certain that the amount is provided in the parameters of the callback function.